# c# compare string irrespective of language

Tags: c#, string

I have a routine that tries to find a specific term in a list of strings.

```
int FindString(string term, List<string> stringList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (stringList[i].Contains(term))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The term is always a Unicode string in English -for example "B4"- while the list of strings contains strings that may be written in other languages. A string might contain "B4" for example but since it was written in Greek, the Contains method returns false when comparing the English and Greek version of basically the same characters.

Is there a way to transform the non-English string so the Contains method will properly return true?

Example term and string (filename in reality):

```
term: B4

string: 19-299-12-Β4.txt
```

Comment: Please provide a concrete working example of the problem you are encountering. String `"B4b"` is `"B4b"` in German and in English, an equality check on these 2 string would always result in `true`.

Comment: I think you need to do a `String.Compare` with the `StringComparison.InvariantCulture` enum passed in.

Comment: Hi, please provide some examples of the strings because the strings don't change based on the input language. It will be easier to assist if you provide the string you're looking for and the one you're searching in.

Comment: If you are looking to use the [`StringComparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.8) flag then consider using the overload of [IndexOf(String, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_) and check if the result is greater than or equal to 0. Example: `if (stringList[i].IndexOf(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)`

Comment: I added a sample term and a sample string where Contains method returns false. When I print the int value of the two Bs I get 66 and 914 respectively.

Comment: The `Β` in your second string is the Greek letter Beta. It's not a German letter, and even an invariant culture comparison doesn't consider them to be variants of the same letter. Despite their very similar appearance, it would be like expecting `P` and `Π` (or `P` and `Ρ` (Rho)) to be treated as the same letter.

Comment: I updated my post with the information by @JLRishe.

Comment: @Tsaras Ok, but they aren't "basically the same characters" (see my edited comment). I think that searching Greek text using English search terms sounds like a fool's errand.

Comment: @JLRishe OK it's clarified I will have to make a separate comparison in case the letter is in Greek, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to "normalize" string based on your custom rules and than perform search.

Since there is no generally accepted mapping that include at least "Latin B" equals "Greek B" you have to build your own - basic dictionary `Dictionary<char,char>` may be enough.

As part of that "normalization" you may also consider digit mapping - for that there is actually official Unicode information available - [GetDigitValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getdigitvalue?view=netframework-4.8).

So overall code to normalize would look like:

```
var source = "А9"; // Cyrilic A9 - "\u0410\u0039"
var map = new Dictionary<char,char> { { 'А', 'A' } }; // Cyrillic to Latin 
var chars = source.Select( c =>
     CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c)==UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber?
           CharUnicodeInfo.GetDigitValue(c).ToString()[0] :
     map.ContainsKey(c) ? map[c] : 
     c);
var result = String.Join("", chars);

var term = "\u0041\u0039"; // Latin A9
Console.WriteLine(source.Contains(term));       
Console.WriteLine(result.Contains(term));
```